How to change PermitRootLogin to no in SSH configuration file using a bash file?
I currently use the following in my bash file to change the SSH configuration from #PermitRootLogin yes to PermitRootLogin no. However, sometimes the SSH configuration file has #PermitRootLogin no and I just want to uncomment it. How can I update my command to work in both cases?
#! /bin/sh

sed -i -e "s/#PermitRootLogin yes/PermitRootLogin no/" /etc/ssh/sshd_config


It feels like you want to enforce PermitRootLogin no every time, so just replace the whole line with your setting.
sed -i -Ee 's/^#?(PermitRootLogin)[[:space:]].*/\1 no/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

And don't forget to restart sshd afterwards.

Try to replace your code with this one :
sed -i -e 's/^\(#*\)PermitRootLogin *(yes|no)/PermitRootLogin no/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Sincerely.

That did not work for me. It still leaves #PermitRootLogin no
